# how to call eval with string

Tags: javascript, eval

I have a string with format `TwoOneFourSeven ^ EightFiveNine` how can i call `eval` with argument of string(above) ?

```
eval(function (p, r, o, x, y, s) {

    y = function (c) {
        return (c < r ? '' : y(parseInt(c / r))) + ((c = c % r) > 35 ? String.fromCharCode(c + 29) : c.toString(36))
    };
    if (!''.replace(/^/, String)) {
        while (o--) {
            s[y(o)] = x[o] || y(o)
        }
        x = [function (y) {
            return s[y]
        }];
        y = function () {
            return '\\w+'
        };
        o = 3
    };
    while (o--) {
        if (x[o]) {
            p = p.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + y(o) + '\\b', 'g'), x[o])
        }
    }
    return p
}('o=D^C;p=9;h=1;q=B^E;s=6;k=2;t=F^A;i=G^I;c=y^u;r=7;f=0;l=5;d=4;n=8;a=w^z;g=x^v;b=3;e=H^W;j=V^X;m=U^S;J=f^j;T=h^i;M=k^g;L=b^a;K=d^e;N=l^m;O=s^t;R=r^q;Q=n^o;P=p^c;', 60, 60, '^^^^^^^^^^Four9Eight^Seven^FourSevenOne^Three^Two4Nine^One^Two6Seven^Two^Nine7Three^FiveSixFive^Four^Eight^Four2Zero^Six^ThreeSixFour^Zero^FiveTwoTwo^Nine^Five^ZeroOneSix^8909^8090^3162^8795^3898^80^81^5219^3127^9348^9090^10629^4355^1070^6588^NineEightTwoFour^Four6ZeroSeven^Three5SixEight^Six4OneZero^ThreeSevenFiveThree^Three9ThreeOne^Eight3NineTwo^TwoSevenSevenFive^Two0FourNine^1337^Six6EightSix^5347^8094^808^8080'.split('\u005e'), 0, {}))
```

Comment: Can you explain what your code does, and what exactly is your question? Especially all of the variable names are completely undescriptive...

Comment: This code is use to convert string format TwoOneFourSeven ^ EightFiveNine to some numbers(port of proxy ip)

Comment: The argument to `eval()` should be the result of calling the function, not the function itself. What are all those cryptic parameters?

Comment: Your code seems to be incomplete, there are unbalanced brackets.

Comment: Is it supposed to be an IIFE?

Comment: Don't post minified code, post it with the original variable and function names so that it's understandable.

Comment: yes it is IIFE.

Comment: @Barmar Assuming the OP has the original code. If they don't then there may be some copyright issues etc.

Comment: @АлександрЗосимчук You still have unmatched brackets, you're missing the closing `)`. And if it's IIFE, you need `(...)` after it, with the arguments in there.

Comment: I don't see how that code translates something like `TwoOneFourSeven` to `2147`. Where is the map between words and numbers?

Comment: Stack Overflow uglyfy code